# Angular return value from subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular5

I need to return a value from the subscribe of a service call. Here is my code:

```
export class RideDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  rides: Ride[];

  constructor(private _rideService: RidesService,
              private _paginator: MatPaginator) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<Ride[]> {

this._rideService.getActiveRides(this._paginator.pageIndex, this._paginator.pageSize).subscribe(
      ridePage => {
        this.rides = ridePage.content;
        this._paginator.length = ridePage.totalElements;
      }
    );

    // i need to return  Observable.of(this.rides);
  }

  disconnect() {
    // No-op
  }

}
```

Returning `Observable.of(this.rides)`  won't work as `this.rides` will be `undefined`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not subscribe in the service, use the [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator instead and subscribe to `connect()`.

RideDataSource:

```ts
export class RideDataSource  {

  connect(): Observable<Ride[]> {
    return this._rideService.getActiveRides(
      this._paginator.pageIndex, 
      this._paginator.pageSize
    ).pipe(
      map(ridePage => {
        this.rides = ridePage.content;
        this._paginator.length = ridePage.totalElements;
        return this.rides;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Some Component:

```ts
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private rideDataSource: RideDataSource) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rideDataSource.connect().subscribe(rides => console.log(rides));
  }
}
```

If you need the data in the component template, then you can do the following:

Some Component Class:

```ts
export class SomeComponent {

  rides = this.rideDataSource.connect()

  constructor(private rideDataSource: RideDataSource) { }
}
```

Some Component Template:

```html
{{ rides | async }}
```