# Assign value returned by Observable.subscribe() to a const

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I'm trying to send a request to my Django API from an Ionic4-Angular front-end, the problem is that I've not become familiar with this tecnology or even javascript yet.
In the following code I'm trying to return the subscribe data and assign it to a const.

```
async getUserLogged() {
    const tkn = await this.authService.getToken();
    const user = await this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/getuser/', {
        token: tkn
      })
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
    console.log(user);

    return user;
  }
```

The first console.log contains the real object i'm searching for.
However, the second one prints a Subscriber object.
Can anyone explain me this behaviour and how can I fix it

Comment: That's how it works, you access the response in the subscription. Without the `.subscribe()`, you would have declared the pipleline without really executing it.

Comment: This was what made streams click for me : https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419100/3634032). When building streams, only subscribe at the very end where you need the data (most often in the component). When handling Observables in intermediate functions (such as methods in an Angular services), just transform the Observable data using operators, do not subscribe to the Observables in those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

callback function of `subscribe` cannot return any value to `user`. it only gets `Subscriber` object as you mentioned which is result of observable.

If you want to use `async`, `await` approach, you need to use `toPromise` method to make an observable a promise.

```ts
async getUserLogged() {
    const tkn = await this.authService.getToken();
    const user = await this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/getuser/', {
        token: tkn
      }).toPromise();
    console.log(user);

    return user;
  }
```

Comment: This works but I still not understand it quite well, did you mean there is another way of working with observables?

Comment: This is another way that work with a Promise. If you want to use observables, you need to change the logic where `getUserLogged` in is used.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would set up this method:

```
getUserLogged() {
  return this.authService.getToken().pipe(
    switchMap(tkn=> {
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/getuser/', {
        token: tkn
      })
   })
  );
}
```

You then use this method as follows:

```
getUserLogged().subscribe(userData => console.log(userData));
```

This approach uses the [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator that only calls `http.post` once `authService.getToken` returns the token.You can find the documentation to all RxJs operators [here](https://rxjs.dev/api).

Answer (score -1):

Converting your observable response to a promise, makes it easy to call from where you need.

```
const getUserLogged = () => {
    const tkn = await this.authService.getToken();
    return this.http
      .post('http://localhost:8000/api/getuser/', {
        token: tkn
      })
      .toPromise();
};

const someOtherFunc = async () => {
  const user = await getUserLogged();
  console.log({ user });
};
```

Comment: Angular's HttpClient returns observables by default.

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, rxjs comes with toPromise.